# Re-installation failed (YES) Package already exists

Tags: android, eclipse, deployment, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

So, I have an app which I am running on real device. When running the app the following dialog is shown. 
[image]

Clicking Yes is followed by `error` in `Console`

**- google-play-services_lib] Installation error! The package already exists.** 
 - Launch failed on device:

I have tried uninstalling app from my phone but didn't work.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: are you trying to install google play service or something?

Comment: I am trying to install app which uses Google play services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to reinstall google-play-services. It's updating automatically by Play Market.
I had problems like yours and let me guess: 
when you debuging app from eclipse - google play services doesnt sign in, but when u release it and download from play market - it works fine.
If its true, so mark your google-services as a library and delete from "java build path" in your app.

```
right click on project-> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects
```

Delete google-play-services from there

Now, you have to obtain **debug certificate SHA1**

1. in Eclipse go to **Window->Preferences**
2. Andoid->Build
   (there you can find **debug certificate SHA1** for debuging)

   1. Go to Android Developper Console https://play.google.com/apps/publish
   2. Select your game in Play service
   3. Go to "linked applications"
   4. Create a NEW linked application android and put it your **debug certificate SHA1**
   5. Wait a few to changes be deployed

You will get two similar links, but with different SHA1 ( one for debugging, second for releasing)

Now, you need to clear the Android Application cache before trying to connect

1. Clear cache of your application
2. Launch your app

I solved my problem like this

Answer (score 1):

That's caused by attempting to install an apk maybe from the ide with debug keystore on a device that has the production apk with the production keystore.  Just ***go into the phones app settings and uninstall the app***.  I get a few of these after I test the upgrade path from the beta store and then go back to developing with the ide.

Comment: I have tried uninstalling app several times but it does not help.

Comment: Sorry you've gone down the reset the phone path.  I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

try doing it through command prompt use:

> adb uninstall PACKAGE_NAME

and see if it works

also try renaming the package name just to be sure.

I feel you are trying to install google-play-services.You don't need to update google play services.From the docs:

> The Google Play services APK
>
> The Google Play services APK contains the individual Google services
>   and runs as a background service in the Android OS. You interact with
>   the background service through the client library and the service
>   carries out the actions on your behalf. An easy-to-use authorization
>   flow is also provided to gain access to the each Google service, which
>   provides consistency for both you and your users.
>
> The Google Play services APK is delivered through the Google Play
>   Store, so updates to the services are not dependent on carrier or OEM
>   system image updates. In general, devices running Android 2.3
>   (Gingerbread) or later and have the Google Play Store app installed
>   receive updates within a few days. This allows you to use the newest
>   APIs in Google Play services and reach most of the devices in the
>   Android ecosystem (devices older than Android 2.3 or devices without
>   the Google Play Store app are not supporte

Comment: I have done what you suggested but no help. Still the same problem.

Yes, I am installing google-play-services as I am using push notifications in the app.